# JSP Iterate over a user-defined class that inherits

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp

I have two entity classes that represent two tables in my database.
The two tables are User and Student. The Student class(userID, studentID, classID) inherits from the User class(id, firstName, lastName, email).
When I query the database for students, I have a List returned. I then want to use that list to iterate over and display the firstName,lastName,email,and classID for each student. However, it only displays the classID. I believe this is because the object is of a Student that only contains three fields (userID, studentID, classID) and doesn't doesn't contain the names and email. However, because the Student class extends the User class, I thought it should still be able to get the other fields.

Here are my classes

User

```
public class User {
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;

public User(){

}

public String getFullName(){
    return firstName +" "+ lastName;
}
public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

Student

```
public class Student extends User {
private int userID;
private int studentID
private int classID

public int getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(int userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

 public int getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
}

public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
}
public int getClassID() {
    return classID;
}

public void setClassID(int classID) {
    this.classID = classID;
}
}
```

JSP

```
        <c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
            <tr>
                <td>${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}</td>
                <td>${student.email}</td>
                <td>${student.classID}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

In my controller class

```
List<Student> students = getStudents();
      output.addObject("students", students);
```

How can I get it to display, user.firstName, user.lastName, user.email, student.classID

Comment: I'd be surprised if this really works for classId, since your getter doesn't match what you wrote in the JSP: getClassId maps to "classId", not "classID".

You should put up the full listing for the JSP too so we can make sure you did everything right there (and maybe fix the Student.java listing that's broken in the middle).

Comment: I changed it to classID

Comment: Is that the whole JSP? If so, you need to import the "c" taglib. Put this on the top of the file:

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

Comment: It isn't my entire JSP. I tried showing the entire JSP file but it isn't displaying correctly because it is using the HTML to edit my text. 

Here is how I add the list.
List<Student> students = getStudents();
          output.addObject("students", students);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSP code seems fine.

If the values are not available in the Student object and should be because of the hierarchy, the problem lies in the code that populates the Student objects after the query is done. You might want to validate how a Student object is created and why the fields which belong to the User object are not set.

Comment: I looked closer at how the student object was being created and you were correct. I was not populating it correctly.